# what prevent windows cpu to work more than 100%?

Tags: windows, unix, operating-system, cpu

today i took my 1st UNIX lesson, so please bear with me if here comes some stupid questions.

In the class the tutor just run 
  ~$: yes "hello, world"
twice, then the CPU goes above 100%, it goes to 1.36 actually, before he killed the 2 yes process.

he said in Solaris, CPU could go to 400%, and still working. slow, but never crash.

what is this cpu percentage, if it's a percentage how come it goes beyond 100%?
and I never observe any CPU percentage more than 100% in windows, if ever it's 80% it's as slow as a worm. is there any windows OS limitation so that it won't go beyond 100%?

Comment: This is certainly not on topic on SO. Not sure if it is on topic on another SE site, such as Superuser.

Comment: sorry about that, i can close this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Neither Unix nor Windows can utilize a CPU more than 100% ... for multi-core / hyperthreading etc. the percentage can be calculated either as the sum as Solaris seems to do it (thus going above 100%) or the average as Windows does it (thus never going above 100%)...

The 1.36 is NOT the same as CPU utilization but it is the "load" which is calculated differently - for a nice explanation see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29

Comment: Thanks Yahia, it's the result when the tutor typed command "uptime", just checked in about: uptime 
uptime [-V]  
DESCRIPTION

uptime gives a one line display of the following information. The current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes. ==> so this is system load average ...

Answer (score 1):

Its a question of % calculation. You either sum each core up and show a total or you show an average over all cores.

If Solaris goes to 400% its for 4 cores at 100%. If 1 core is at 100% it shows 100%.

In Windows is at 100% this equals to 4 cores at 100%. If 1 core is at 100% it shows 25%.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of CPU percent is simply different for multi core systems. Windows calculates the average, solaris the sum. So if all cores in a quad-core system are busy, windows will display 100%, and solaris will say it's 400%. That doesn't mean that those 400% percent are somehow faster than the 100% on windows, it's just a display convention.